# How to print a huge page while preserving Style?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer, screenshot

I tried all possible standard options and I think that it will take some hack to do it the right way.

Pressing <kbd>PrtSc</kbd>, pasting to Paint and cutting off the margins would work, but I would like to get a solution for multiple pages. Repeating <kbd>PrtSc</kbd> multiple times is out of the question.

Each time I'm trying to print a page, for instance [this Twitter page](http://twitter.com/qweqwe), I get something like this no matter what OS or browser I use. How can I get it to preserve the style while doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could do a screenshot (using something like [Aviary](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ncgcgghbabbopfcpgcjpfffdgnbadegf) for Chrome) and print it.

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry, but all screenshot plugins that I tried (for FF/Chrome, incl. Aviary) seem to be of low quality and can handle only smaller web pages. None was capable of printing this link for example: http://omikheev.spb.ru/Twitter%20_%20Search%20-%20@MedvedevRussia.htm, so if you know some better ones - I'll be glad to mark this question back to answered

Comment: You are pushing the envelope here

Comment: no! browsers have no problem printing that out as PDF at all, I'm just looking for a better formatting

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be a 'PDF printer' creation program, personally i use Bullzip for many online banking pages which do not otherwise print correctly. Just 'print' them to the PDF creator then actually print them from there! :)

Comment: have you tried to PDF print a twitter page? it looks ugly

Comment: #don't #think #twitter #was #designed #with #printing #in #mind

Comment: it's not **just** Twitter, as I mentioned in the question...

Comment: If you want it exactly as *seen on screen* then you need to take the formatting into your own hands rather than rely on whatever webpage layout each individual site happens to use... Simple answer - alt+Print Screen

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found out how to do that!

Twitter style gets broken when you print due to the fact that HTML stylesheets can have media types assigned to them, thus providing different styles for different media (printer, screen etc).

So, I saved Twitter page that I need to print to an HTML file (choosing Web Page, complete) and looked into HTML sources. I saw that the main CSS was having `media="screen"` - which meant that this CSS had no effect for printing.

I removed just this single `media="screen"` text from the HTML and saved it.

Now Twitter page gets printed the right way!

This info will be also useful to other people trying to print or take a screenshot of a large huge web pages.

When your screenshot taking plugin/add-on fails due to the web page size (in case of Firefox it results in this exception in Error console:

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... "Component returned failure code:
0x8007000e (NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY) [nsIDOMHTMLCanvasElement.getContext]"  
nsresult: "0x8007000e (NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY)"  location: "JS frame :: 
chrome://uploadscreenshot/content/uploadscreenshot.js :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: 
line 211"  data: no]
```

) you printing to a PDF printer and this style editing method will help you!

Comment: This is merely a work-around, why not save an image and print that image?

Comment: if it's a single web page then certainly saving an image would work, but when it is a huge page (1Mb HTML) - saving an image becomes impossible.... just a thought - _1Mb HTML should not be considered huge these days_

Comment: There is no relationship between the size of a webpage and the size of an image, consider 1Mb HTML that just renders a white page. Even if it's a page full of stuff, it'll generate a big image but it won't be impossible. If the page can be drawn to your screen, it can also be saved to an image file...

Comment: I never said that there was a relationship between the size of a webpage and the size of an image. It's just impossible to generate an image if the web page is very long due to the fact that browsers fail to work with big canvases, e.g. Chrome fails if canvas height is greater than 32767 https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=649924

Comment: The bug you refer to is marked as `RESOLVED / FIXED` and the new implementation is not limited in size...

Comment: If you got time please feel free to submit a new bug there... Get latest Firefox (8.0.1), install a screenshot app that lets you capture full web page (like [Screenshot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/screenshot/), load [1 Mb page](http://omikheev.spb.ru/Twitter%20_%20Search%20-%20@MedvedevRussia.htm), try to capture full page, get NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY. Reproducible: ALWAYS, Platforms: Linux and Windows

Comment: Chrome is better - it doesn't throw an Exception - it just doesn't produce any image. I don't have time to search if they have a bug for that or not, I'm fine with removing `media="screen"` and printing as PDF.

Comment: You need to check out the latest nightly before drawing such conclusion. Not throwing an exception is certainly not better. One suggestion: Use Firebug so you don't have to download the HTML... :)